# Not to wrap one with/end with, into another with/end with statement

Tags: excel, vba

Elegant code and code readability question

This is my code and it works fine.

There is a contract number and the date in the beginning of the Word documents I need to process, which I need to extract and write into respective cells in a spreadsheet.

My question refers to the parts of the code where one with/end with statement is wrapped in another with/end with statement. 3rd and 4th paragraph in the code, where I'm looking for the wildcards expressions.

```
Sub ExtractRepertorNmbrUsingWildcards()   
Application.ScreenUpdating = False        

    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim kompar As Word.Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim regEx As Object
    Dim matches As Collection
    Dim match As Variant
    Dim repNmbr As String
    Dim cesja As Range
    Dim startPos As Long
    Dim endPos As Long

   'Assigning object variables
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    Set excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.ActiveDocument
    Set ws = excelApp.ActiveSheet
    Set rng = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
    Set matches = New Collection
    Set cesja = ActiveSheet.Range("A10:J50").Find("cesja /", , xlValues)
    Debug.Print cesja.Address

    With wordApp.ActiveDocument.Range
         With .Find
             .Text = "<[0-9 ]{1;7}/[0-9]{4}>"       'contract number
             .MatchWildcards = True
             .Wrap = wdFindStop
             .Forward = True
             .Execute
         End With
      If .Find.Found = True Then matches.Add Replace(.Text, " ", "")   'macro is adding it to the collection
      Debug.Print "# of items is"; matches.Count
    End With

    With wordApp.ActiveDocument.Range
         With .Find
             .Text = "<[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{4}r."     'date
             .MatchWildcards = True
             .Wrap = wdFindStop
             .Forward = True
             .Execute
         End With
      If .Find.Found = True Then matches.Add .Text     'macro is adding it to the same collection as above on the next free record
      Debug.Print "# of items is"; matches.Count
    End With

    For Each match In matches
      Debug.Print match
    Next match
```

What I don't understand is why in this part of the code (and next code paragraph as well):

```
  With wordApp.ActiveDocument.Range
         With .Find
             .Text = "<[0-9 ]{1;7}/[0-9]{4}>"       'contract number
             .MatchWildcards = True
             .Wrap = wdFindStop
             .Forward = True
             .Execute
         End With
      If .Find.Found = True Then matches.Add Replace(.Text, " ", "")
      Debug.Print "# of items is"; matches.Count
  End With
```

one with/end with statement, is wrapped in another one.

How should this part of the code be written, to avoid this unnecessary wrapping / double with/end with statement. I'm asking how a pro coder would written it?

Please correct this code, to make it efficient, good looking, readable and short.

Comment: It doesn't look redundant to me. The 2nd `With` is to set the `.Find` properties. And after that, `.Text` (as a `.Range` property) is added to a collection. However, to have someone have a proper look at your code you might want to post at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: This code is fine and readable. Removing the inner `With` will result in `.Find.Text = "<[0-9 ]{1;7}/[0-9]{4}>"`, `.Find.MatchWildcards = True`, `.Find.Wrap = wdFindStop` etc which results in a natural urge to factor it out the common `.Find` with its own `With`.

Comment: Use [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)